# MS Excel create dropdown list on sheet2 based on data in sheet1, column1

Tags: excel

On Worksheet1, I have a list of applications in column A. On Worksheet2, I have a list of servers. I want to add a column to the servers worksheet to identify which application the server supports. I would like there to be a dropdown of available applications from Worksheet1, column A. How can I set that up?

Comment: data -> data validation -> allow: list (in-cell dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

To use a list on one worksheet for *DV* on another worksheet:

One *Sheet1* assign a *Name* to the list:

[image]

Then on the other worksheet apply the *DV* using that *Name*:

[image]

Comment: thanks so so much. so simple and yet I could not find that answer in my search anywhere!!